# I'm trying to create an if statement that will only display my button link for tickets if its under 'admission-event'... what is wrong with my code?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, conditional-content

```
<!-- column links -->
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-2 links">
    <?php  if ( is_category( 'admission-event' ) ) { ?>

      <a href="https://www.eventbrite.com/d/ut--salt-lake-city/vocalocity/" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="btn btn-secondary tickets" <?php echo $open_new_window; ?>>BUY TICKETS</a>

      <a href="<?php echo $post_link  ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="btn btn-secondary more-info" <?php echo $open_new_window; ?>>MORE INFO<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a>

    <?php } else { ?>

      <a href="<?php echo $post_link  ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="btn btn-secondary more-info" <?php echo $open_new_window; ?>>MORE INFO<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a>

    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <!-- /column links -->
```

Comment: Can use please try with in_category('admission-event') instead of is_category('admission-event');

Comment: I’ll try that! Thank you so much for your help. It’s greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you got solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

[`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) is the wrong function to use here. That category is checking *Are we on the archive page for the given category?*

The correct function to use would be [`has_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/), which is checking *Is this post in the given category*?

Comment: Thank you so much!